# How can I find the percentage of records in a table in DB2?

Tags: select, db2

I have a single table - drivers
I want to know what percentage of the driver's have been terminated this month compared to all the active drivers. I think I have made it very complicated and while it does return a result it is just a 0. I tried using the cast as decimal but that doesn't work for me either as the calculation still results in 0.

```
WITH X AS
( 
SELECT
CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL (5,2)) TERMINATED,
0 ACTIVE
FROM DRIVER WHERE 
MONTH(TERMINATION_DATE) = MONTH(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) AND YEAR(TERMINATION_DATE) = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
0 TERMINATED,
CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) ACTIVE
FROM DRIVER WHERE
ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'
)

SELECT
CAST(SUM(TERMINATED)/(SUM(ACTIVE) + SUM(TERMINATED)*100) AS DECIMAL (10,2))
FROM X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are a bit off, instead of

```
SUM(TERMINATED)/(SUM(ACTIVE) + SUM(TERMINATED)*100)
```

it should read

```
SUM(TERMINATED)/(SUM(ACTIVE) + SUM(TERMINATED))*100
```

You got a too small number, that's why it wouldn't fit into two decimal places.

I would rewrite Your query like this:

```
WITH begin_of_month(begin_of_month) AS (VALUES CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE)-1) DAYS),
X AS (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS terminated, 0 AS active
    FROM driver
    WHERE termination_date >= begin_of_month
      AND termination_date <  begin_of_month + 1 MONTH --index, if present, can be used!
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS terminated, COUNT(*) AS active
    FROM driver
    WHERE active_in_disp = 'True'
)
SELECT CAST(FLOAT(SUM(TERMINATED))/(SUM(ACTIVE) + SUM(TERMINATED))*100 AS DECIMAL (10,2)) --CAST only if You wish to display with 2 decimal places
  FROM X
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reaching out and for pointing out the issues with the parentheses (it is an ongoing problem I have :D). I tried your query and I get an error "BEGIN_OF_MONTH" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703

Comment: Try `TERMINATION_DATE BETWEEN FIRST_DAY (CURRENT DATE) AND LAST_DAY (CURRENT DATE)`, if you are on Db2 V11.1 or newer. Or `TERMINATION_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT DATE - (DAYOFMONTH (CURRENT DATE) - 1) AND CURRENT DATE - (DAYOFMONTH (CURRENT DATE) - 1) + 1 MONTH - 1` if you are on some older Db2 version.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you both very much for all your help. I am sure I would have been spinning my wheels still without these answers. :)